# Write a query to get output like this A1 A2 A3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15

Tags: oracle

I have An Table Like This:-

```
C1    C2
A1    3
B4    8
C9    15
```

And I Want My Output Like This:-

```
A1
A2
A3
B4
B5
B6
B7
B8
C9
C10
C11
C12
C13
C14
C15
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46346372/1509264

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/670df/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( C1, C2 ) AS
  SELECT 'A1',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B4',  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C9', 15 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH ts ( alpha, value, max ) AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR( c1, 1, 1 ), TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( c1, 2 ) ), c2 FROM t
UNION ALL
  SELECT alpha, value + 1, max FROM ts WHERE value < max
)
SELECT alpha || value AS output
FROM   ts
ORDER BY alpha, value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/670df/3/0)**:

```
| OUTPUT |
|--------|
|     A1 |
|     A2 |
|     A3 |
|     B4 |
|     B5 |
|     B6 |
|     B7 |
|     B8 |
|     C9 |
|    C10 |
|    C11 |
|    C12 |
|    C13 |
|    C14 |
|    C15 |
```

Comment: Perfect! @MT0 and faster in typping thsn me :D